# How to fix 'pouchDB not defined' in svelte app

Tags: pouchdb, svelte

I am trying to set up pouchDB in my svelte application. When I run the app, an error occurs (ReferenceError: PouchDB is not defined)

To include pouchDB in my application, i used the  tag to link to a cdn. When I only link to the cdn, my application runs fine. But if I try to add any pouchDB code to my project it states that it is not dfined.

```html
<script>
    import Timer from './timer.svelte';
</script>
<svelte:head>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
<Timer/>
```

I expected to be able to include pouchDB code in my timer.svelte component [var db = new PouchDB('kittens');] but when I do it states that pouchDB is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I wonder if this is a timing problem, where your component renders, adds the CDN link to the head, but then starts trying to do work before that script finishes downloading? If that's the case, then putting the `<script />` in the head of your `index.html` or `template.html` could help.